# How do I make the tab title scroll smoothly?

Tags: javascript

I'm setting up a website and I wish to make the title scroll. The current code I have does the trick but it isn't smooth.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
var space = " ";
var speed = "135";
var pos = 0;
var msg = "this is a title";
function Scroll()
{
 document.title = msg.substring(pos, msg.length) + space + msg.substring(0,pos);
 pos++;
 if (pos > msg.length) pos = 0;
  window.setTimeout("Scroll()", speed);
}
Scroll();
-->
</script>
```

Currently, the scrolling in the tab works but it's really jittery/clunky and not smooth. I wish to make it smooth.

Comment: You can only "scroll" the tab title by changing the text. There's no other way. what you have is a good as it gets. The only thing you can change is the speed. Also, use `window.setInterval(Scroll, speed);` instead, please (move the line out of the function, lose the `Scroll()` call at the bottom.)

Comment: You could try using a simple CSS animation - use `position: relative;` on the element containing the text, `overflow: hidden;` on the container, and animate the `left` or `right` property?

Comment: @ChrisG thanks! I guess I'll have to live with rough scrolling :-(